# WCF Custom Header does not Appear in Service

Tags: wcf, custom-headers

I was wondering if somebody came across this issue and has an answer or pointer. I implemented IClientMessageInspector to add a header to my soap message on the client. So, inside BeforeSendREquest I call MessageHeader.CreateHeader. This seems to work because i see the message in Fiddler with the header in the collection. On the service side, i have a custom authenticationManager. When the service call enters the implementation I dont see the header i inserted. I have a feeling the ServiceModel stack is skipping my header during deserialization but not sure. Also, not sure on how to fix this if its truly what is happening. Maybe implement the equivalent of IClientMessageInspector on the service side?

Any idea/pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Some code would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

In server-side WCF code, to act upon a SOAP header from the client (inserted by IClientMessageInspector), I have used an implementation of IDispatchMessageInspector. In its AfterReceiveRequest() method, I use request.Headers.FindHeader() to see if the expected header is present.

Comment: thanks. this is a good solution but not in my situation. I need the header before the execution of the AfterReceiveRequest. I need it in the authenticationManager. I figured out why i am not seeing my custom headers (i left the relevant detail out of my question). I am using a WS binding with security set to message. This requires for the custom headers to be signed. I am not sure how to do that as of yet. I suspect its done with a MessageContract. But when i turned off message security i am able to see my headers.